# not bound to TTS engine Huawei p9

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a problem with com.android.acapela.tts. The code is working. When i launch application the tts works like clock but if the aplication close and then recall, tts doesn't work. the log is showed error "*W/TextToSpeech: speak failed: not bound to TTS engine*" It's crazy situation. I try to emulate it on the Samsung S3 and  the error doesn't arise. Also error arise if application launch and stay without user activity over 2 minutes.
May i check that tts is bonded?

`

```
package com.gloomyad.soundacapella;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

    //TTS object
    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    //status check code
    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    //create the Activity
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //get a reference to the button element listed in the XML layout
        Button speakButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);
        //listen for clicks
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

       //check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    //respond to button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //get the text entered
        EditText enteredText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);

    }


    //speak the user text
    private void speakWords(String speech) {

        //speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    //act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }
            else {
                //no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    //setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: What are you doing in pause/resume/destroy?

Comment: I don't do anything of these. This situation occurs when screen is turned off and  then i wake up my phone. I guess it must relate to close activity.